# what can we conclude from the transposed equation?

Tags: matrices

After lots of work I discovered that the equation $B^T \cdot x = 0$ has non-trivial solution, I want to conclude that also $B \cdot x = 0$ has non-trivial solution but I can't find a way to prove it.

Any help will help :) thanks

(And sorry about that I don't know latex or the math format you are using here)

edit: B is from the order **n x m**

Comment: Do you know whether $n$ or $m$ is larger?

Comment: @Hetebrij if n=m it would be easy, if m > n I would also know how to solve it (more variables than equations) the case of n > m is the hard case for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $n > m$.
Then we can define 
$$B = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 &0 &\cdots &0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 &\cdots & 0 \\ \vdots &0 & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots  \\ \vdots &\vdots & \ddots &\ddots  & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\ 0&0&0&0&0 \\ \vdots &\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots \\0&0&0&0&0\end{matrix}\right).$$
 So we start with $m \times m $ identity matrix, and then $n-m \times m$ $0$-matrix.

So $Bx=0$ iff $x=0$ otherwise on of the first $m$ components of $Bx$ wouldn't be zero.
On the other hand, we have $B^T = \left( \begin{matrix} I_m & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$, so if we take $x=\left( \underset{m \textrm{ times}}{0 , \dots , 0}, 1 , 0 \dots, 0 \right)^T$, we have $B^Tx = 0$, so $B^T$ has a non-trivial solution.

Comment: If B is not square $Bx$ and $B^T x$ can't both make sense.

Comment: @Paul It can make sense if I abuse notation. In the first case $x$ is a generic element of $\mathbb{R}^m$, and in the second case $x$ is a specified element of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\det{B}=\det{B^T}$.  What do you know about $\det B^T$?

Comment: I really wanted to use it, but B is from the order n x m (forgot to mention) Is it still possible to use det in such a case?

Comment: If B is not square you can't pre-multiply x by both $B$ and $B^T$.

Comment: oh ok so probably my whole way is wrong